# why isn't $\int \ln\left((x+1)(x+2)\right)\ dx = 1/(x+1) + 1/(x+2) + C$?

Tags: integration

by the product rule for Logarithm, 
$$\ln(xy) = \ln(x) + \ln(y) $$

the question is, $\int \ln\left(x^2 + 3x + 2\right)\ dx = \int \ln\left((x+1)(x+2)\right)\ dx$
so, I thought I could divide them into $\int\ln(x+1)\ dx + \int\ln(x+2)\ dx$ and the answer will be $\1/(x+1) + 1(x+2) + C$,

however, the system gave me that that is wrong answer and system showed another answer with using another formular.

So I want to know why my answer is wrong. 
Thank you!

Comment: Because differentiation is not finding the reciprocal.

Comment: Because you're taking the integral, not the derivative.

Comment: Common mistake! You need to integrate $\ln(x)$ using integration by parts. You are thinking of the similar looking rule that $\int 1/x\,dx= \ln |x|+C$.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: man.... please go learn some basics in math. get some education

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because $$\int \ln (x) dx\neq \frac{1}{x}+C$$ It's the other way around: $$\int \frac{1}{x}dx = \ln (x) + C$$
You can try to derive the result: $$\int \ln (x) dx = x\ln x - x + C $$

Comment: I made a mistake, Thanks! I understand!

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because the derivative of the natural logarithm is the reciprocal function. The antiderivative of the natural logarithm function is:
$$ \int \ln x \, dx = x \ln x - x + C $$
So:
\begin{align*}
\int \ln(x^2 + 3x + 2) \, dx &= \int \ln[(x+1)(x+2)] \, dx \\
&= \int \ln[(x+1)(x+2)] \, dx \\
&= \int [\ln(x+1) + \ln(x+2)] \, dx \\
&= (x+1)\ln(x+1) - (x+1) + (x+2)\ln(x+2) - (x+2) + C \\[5pt]
&= (x+1)\ln(x+1) + (x+2)\ln(x+2) - 2x + C \\[5pt]
&= x\ln(x^2+3x+2) + \ln(x+1) + 2\ln(x+2) - 2x + C \\
\end{align*}

Comment: I made a mistake, Thanks! I understand!